# Do I need to get all the stray fairies?

Tags: zelda-majoras-mask-3d

The Great Fairy in Clock Town gave me her mask and asked me to get all the stray fairies in various areas.

I know I missed quite a few in Woodfall and I am not sure I want to go back through that dungeon again just to get them.

Is it going to screw up my game if I don't? What do I get for getting all of them each time?

Comment: It's very helpful to get all the Stray Fairies as you get upgrades for doing so.

Comment: Incidentally, the Great Fairy Mask (which you get from the Great Fairy in clocktown the second time you visit her) is extremely helpful for finding them.

Answer (score 2):

**No**. With the exception of the first set of stray fairies that grant you the ability to use magic, the rest of the stray fairies are not required. They're like the gold skultulas in Ocarina of Time. The rewards for catching them all are as follows:

- Woodfall: Double magic meter
- Snowhead: Stronger spin attack
- Great Bay Temple: Double defense
- Stone Tower: Great Fairy Sword

While none of these are required, the double magic meter from the Swamp Great Fairy is extremely useful to have.

Comment: This looks like the N64 list. Although I've not finished Woodfall yes, I've heard that the order of the rewards has changed, specifically that Woodfall and Snowhead have been swapped.

Comment: In any case they're not required for any%

Comment: Each one has an entry in the Bomber's Notebook.  And having completed Woodfall and its faries, the first reward was Double Magic Meter, which is actually a nice change seeing as how quickly you burn through magic in the Mountain area.